# Why does gsutil cp require storage.objects.delete on versioned bucket?

Tags: google-cloud-storage, gsutil

I'm using a service account to upload a file to Google Cloud Storage bucket that has versioning. I want to keep the service account privileges minimal, it only ever needs to upload files so I don't want to give it permission to delete files, but the upload fails (only after streaming everything!) saying it requires delete permission.

Shouldn't it be creating a new version instead of deleting?

Here's the command:

```
cmd-that-streams | gsutil cp -v - gs://my-bucket/${FILE}
```

```
ResumableUploadAbortException: 403 service-account@project.iam.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.objects.delete access to my-bucket/file
```

I've double checked that versioning is enabled on the bucket

```
> gsutil versioning get gs://my-bucket
gs://my-bucket: Enabled
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The permission `storage.objects.delete` is required if you are executing the `gsutl cp` command as per [cloud storage gsutil commands](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-gsutil).

> Command: cp
>
> Required permissions:
>
> - storage.objects.list* (for the destination bucket)
> - storage.objects.get (for the source objects)
> - storage.objects.create (for the destination bucket)
> - storage.objects.delete** (for the destination bucket)
>
> **This permission is only required if you don't use the -n flag and you insert an object that has the same name as an object that already
> exists in the bucket.

Google docs suggests to use -n (do not overwrite an existing file) so `storage.objects.delete` won't be required. But your use case uses versioning and you will be needing to overwrite, thus you will **need to add** **`storage.objects.delete`** on your permissions.

I tested this with a bucket versioning is enabled and only has 1 version. Service account that have roles [Storage Object Creator and Storage Object Viewer](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-roles).

See screenshot for the commands and output:
[image]

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping i'd done something wrong cause it seems bonkers that I need to grant my service account the privilege to delete things when my goal is to preserve them

Answer (score 4):

If you're overwriting an object, regardless of whether or not its parent bucket has versioning enabled, you must have `storage.objects.delete` permission for that object.

Versioning works such that when you delete the "live" version of an object, that version is marked as a "noncurrent" version (and [the timeDeleted field](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects#resource) is populated).  In order to create a new version of an object when a live version already exists (i.e. overwriting the object), the transaction that happens is:

- Delete the current version
- Create a new version that becomes the "live" or "current" version