# GCS: How to backup and retain versions with a least privilege service account

Tags: google-cloud-storage, gsutil

I want to set up a service account that can save away backups of a file into Google Cloud Storage on a daily basis.

I was going to do it using object versioning and a life cycle policy that maintains the most recent 30 versions of the file.

However, I've discovered that [gsutil requires the delete privilege to create a new version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66129154/why-does-gsutil-cp-require-storage-objects-delete-on-versioned-bucket/66130603#66130603) of the same file.

It seems a bit nuts to me to give a backup process delete privileges and not really in step with the principle of least privilege since my understanding is that this gives the service account the ability to do `gsutil rm -a` and nuke all versions of the backup in one go.

What, then, is the best, least privilege way to achieve this?

I could append a timestamp to the filename each time, but then I can't use lifecycle management and would have to write my own script to determine which are the recent 30 and delete the rest.

Is there a better/easier way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The best way I can think of to solve this is to have two service accounts -- one that can only create objects (creating your backups using timestamps), and one that can list and delete them.

- Account 1 would create your backups, using timestamped filenames to avoid overwriting and thus requiring `storage.objects.delete` permission.
- The credentials for Account 2 would be used for running a script that lists your backup objects and deletes all but the most recent 30 -- you could run this script as a cronjob on a VM somewhere, or only run it when a new backup is uploaded by utilizing Cloud Pub/Sub [to trigger a Cloud Function](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/tut-pub-sub).

Answer (score 1):

We've ended up going with just saving to a different filename (eg `backup-YYYYMMDD`) and using retention policy to delete that file after 30 days.

It's not water tight, if backup fails for 30 days then all versions will be deleted, but we think we've put enough in place that someone would notice that before 30 days.

We didn't like leaving it up to a script to do the deleting because:

1. It's more error prone
2. It means we still end up with a service account with the ability to delete files, and we were really aiming to limit that privilege.